# Puppet - mySQL not remotely accessible upon setup (workbench)

Tags: mysql, puppet

I used Puppet's mySQL module to bring it up like this.

The workstation ip is 172.16.1.49 and JIRA(mySQL) VM is 172.16.1.47 (Puppet Master is 172.16.1.80);

I'm trying to access mySQL server using workbench mySQL client tool from workstation 172.16.1.49 (hence @172.16.1.49 in the grant).

Usually I know I can remotely access if I can view htp:/172.16.1.47:3306 on the browser.
On mySQL VM, if I do htp:/localhost:3306, I see some messages that means I can access the mySQL server. But htp:/172.16.1.47:3306 on itself doesn't work either.

Where the heck in my Puppet for mySQL code, did I mess up? I think somewhere in my puppet code, I am not allowing mySQL server to allow remote access.

```
    class { '::mysql::server':
     root_password           => 'secret',
     remove_default_accounts => true,
     override_options        => $override_options
     }


     ::mysql::db { 'mydb':
     user     => 'jira',
     password => 'secret',
     dbname   => 'jiraDB',
     host     => 'localhost',

    }

    mysql_grant { 'jira@localhost/*.*':
      ensure     => 'present',
      options    => ['GRANT'],
      privileges => ['ALL'],
      table      => '*.*',
      user       => 'jira@localhost' ,
    }


    mysql_grant { 'jira@172.16.1.49/*.*':
      ensure     => 'present',
      options    => ['GRANT'],
      privileges => ['ALL'],
      table      => '*.*',
      user       => 'jira@172.16.1.49' ,
    }

    mysql_grant { 'root@172.16.1.49/*.*':
      ensure     => 'present',
      options    => ['GRANT'],
      privileges => ['ALL'],
      table      => '*.*',
      user       => 'root@172.16.1.49' ,
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
node 'your hostname' { class {'mysql::server':} }

class mysql::server {

package { "mysql-server": ensure => installed }
package { "mysql": ensure => installed }

service { "mysqld":
enable => true,
ensure => running,
require => Package["mysql-server"],
}

file { "/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf":
owner => "mysql", group => "mysql",
source => "puppet:///mounted-storage/my.cnf",
notify => Service["mysqld"],
require => Package["mysql-server"],
}

file { "/etc/my.cnf":
require => File["/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf"],
ensure => "/var/lib/mysql/my.cnf",
}

}
```